# OOP with jQuery and Babel

Tags: jquery, oop, babeljs

I'm trying to brake some jQuery code following OOP principles. The code is partially working. The addCss() method is working, moveRight() doesn't.

HTML

```
<div class="_slider">
      <a href="#" class="_slider_next">&#10095;</a>
      <a href="#" class="_slider_prev">&#10094;</a>
      <ul>
          <li>SLIDE 1</li>
          <li>SLIDE 2</li>
          <li>SLIDE 3</li>
          <li>SLIDE 4</li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
```

JS

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class Carousel {    
    constructor() {
        this.slider = $("._slider");
        this.sliderUl = $("._slider ul");
        this.next = $("_slider_next");
        this.sliderLastCh = $("._slider ul li:last-child");
        this.sliderFirstCh = $("._slider ul li:first-child");
        this.slideCount = $("._slider ul li").length;
        this.slideWidth = $("._slider ul li").width();
        this.slideHeight = $("._slider ul li").height();
        this.sliderUlWidth = this.slideCount * this.slideWidth;
        this.events();
    }

events() {
    $(document).ready(this.addCss.bind(this));

    this.next.click(this.moveRight.bind(this));

    $(document).ready(
        setInterval(function () {
            this.moveRight;
        }, 3000)
    );
}

addCss() {        
    this.slider.css({ width: this.slideWidth, height: this.slideHeight });     
    this.sliderUl.css({ width: this.sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - this.slideWidth });     
    this.sliderLastCh.prependTo(this.sliderUl);
}

moveRight() {
    this.sliderUl.animate({
        left: - this.slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        this.sliderFirstCh.appendTo(this.sliderUl);
        this.sliderUl.css('left', '');
    });
  };
```

}

```
export default Carousel;
```

The slides should be changing on click as well as automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several issues here. The most prevalent issue though is to do with the scope of `this`. In the function body itself, it's fine. However, in the `setInterval()` and 
`animate()` callbacks the scope is the `window`, not the current Class. As such you need to cache the scope of `this` in a variable at the level required, then use it in those callbacks. In the example below I used `_this`.

Also, the two document.ready handlers can be combined, you need to wrap the logic in second document.ready in an anonymous function, and you need to place `()` after `this.moveRight` in order to actually invoke the function.

With all that said, try this:

```js
class Carousel {
  constructor() {
    this.slider = $("._slider");
    this.sliderUl = $("._slider ul");
    this.next = $("._slider_next");
    this.sliderLastCh = $("._slider ul li:last");
    this.sliderFirstCh = $("._slider ul li:first");
    this.slideCount = $("._slider ul li").length;
    this.slideWidth = $("._slider ul li").width();
    this.slideHeight = $("._slider ul li").height();
    this.sliderUlWidth = this.slideCount * this.slideWidth;
    this.events();
  }

  events() {
    var classScope = this;    
    this.next.click(this.moveRight.bind(this));

    $(document).ready(function() {
      classScope.addCss();
      
      setInterval(function() {
        classScope.moveRight();
      }, 3000)
    });
  }

  addCss() {
    this.slider.css({
      width: this.slideWidth,
      height: this.slideHeight
    });
    
    this.sliderUl.css({
      width: this.sliderUlWidth,
      marginLeft: -this.slideWidth
    });
    
    this.sliderLastCh.prependTo(this.sliderUl);
  }

  moveRight() {    
    var classScope = this;    
    
    this.sliderUl.animate({
      left: -this.slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      console.log('slide moved right...');
      classScope.sliderFirstCh.appendTo(classScope.sliderUl);
      classScope.sliderUl.css('left', '');
    });
  };
}

var c = new Carousel();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="_slider">
  <a href="#" class="_slider_next">&#10095;</a>
  <a href="#" class="_slider_prev">&#10094;</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li>SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li>SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If someone don't like underscores in `_this`, I've seen approach to name it `that`.

Comment: A better naming might be `classScope` just to make it clear what it's referring to. If possible making it an arrow function will eliminate this issue entirely.

Comment: You're both right. I've renamed it to `classScope` as that's a more accurate description of its content and purpose.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that was the issue, still struggling with the this keyword. Now the problem is that only the second slide is repeating. It starts with the slide 1 and then only the slide 2 goes in circles, both on auto and click.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest starting a new question about that. Remember to include a working example which shows the slides, though.